# XP doesn't boot normally, requires CD to boot

Tags: windows-xp, boot

I have a situation in which my Windows XP doesn't boot if there is not a Windows XP CD inserted. I am facing this problem for the first time. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: What happens when you try to boot? Be as precise as possible.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a guess.
Without a more detailed description of what exactly happens when you turn the computer on I can't be more specific.

I presume that in your case the CD starts to boot.
You get the message 'Press any key to continue boot from CD' and you DON'T press anything.
After the timeout (some 10 seconds) the normal boot from harddisk begins.

Seems you changed the order in which the BIOS tries from which device the computer can boot.
In some computers if the CD has priority over the harddisk it really needs a bootable CD to be present.
It can also be that you removed the harddisk from the list of bootable devices alltogether. (This won't prevent the CD to hand-over control to the harddisk, just prevents the harddisk from booting without help.)

I would check the Bios settings related to boot-devices. Something appears to be iffy there.

Comment: Yes, I'm getting press any key to continue to bot from CD when I insert CD. BIOS settings are correct. First boots HDD, then CD-ROM

Comment: That's weird. Seems the bootloader files are damaged. From a Windows Command Prompt try the command "fixboot". That might help. If that doesn't do the trick boot from the CD and go into "Recovery Console". From there run "Fixboot".

Comment: Bootloader are fine, tryed this http://icrontic.com/article/repair_windows_xp reparing method. Problem was in jumpers

Answer (score 0):

I have found solution. HDD jumbers was set to slave mode and have trigered this situation. Setted back to master mode and problem gone.

Comment: The HD set to slave mode is (in terms of booting) effectively the same as removing the HD from the list of bootable devices in the Bios. My first guess wasn't so bad ;-)